# balanced expression with stacks

Tags: c++, stack

please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong? 
 I need to make sure the expressions are balanced
I tried everything but I don't even get errors

```
int main() {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("input.txt");

    string exp;
    cout << "Enter an expression ";
    while (getline(infile, exp)) {
        cout << exp << ": ";
        if (matcher(exp))
            cout << "Matched ok" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Match error" << endl;
        cout << "Enter an expression: ";
    }

    cout << "--- Done ---" << endl;

    return 0;
}

int matcher(string expression) {
    stack<char> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        if (isOpener(expression[i]))
            s.push(expression[i]);
        else if (isCloser(expression[i])) {
            if (s.empty()) return 1;    
            char opener = s.top();
            s.pop();
            if (!matches(opener, expression[i])) return 1;
        }
    }

    if (!s.empty()) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: Where is the `matches` function defined? `matches(opener, expression[i])`?

Comment: @user3612601 Then it would be better, if you mention it in the question.

Comment: @user3612601 There is an *edit* button (link) below the question. Please use it and add the functions into the question, not into a comment.

Comment: i tried it wont let me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obivous problem -- your `matcher` function appears to return `1` for failure (does not match) and `0` for success, but your `main` prints `ok` if `matcher` returns non-zero...

Comment: I think it worked, I'm gonna try to add more expressions see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I will assume `isOpener()` and `matches()` work as intended, since you aren't showing them.

If so, the problem is that you're misinterpreting `int -> bool` conversions. A zero converts to `false` and a non-zero integer converts to `true`. You'd be better off declaring `matcher()` to return `bool` and return `true` or `false` from it directly. You'll want to return `false` there where you now return `1` and `true` there where you now return `0`.